# Variable fonts in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, uifontdescriptor, variable-fonts

The following code allows to create a font with different weights.

```swift
func makeFont(weight: CGFloat, size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    var attributesDict = [String: Any]()
    attributesDict["Weight"] = weight
    /* Rubik-Light - is a variable font */
    let fontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor(
        fontAttributes: [
            UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.name : "Rubik-Light",
            kCTFontVariationAttribute as UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName : attributesDict
        ]
    )
    return UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: size)
}
```

It works fine on ios 13 and below, but doesn't work on iOS 14. Is there any solution?

Comment: what does it mean "doesn`t work" ? Can you share the result ?

Comment: @zeytin "Weight" attribute of valiable font is ignored.

Answer (score 9):

Solved.
iOS 14 expects attribute ID instead of its name ("Weight").

So, attributeDict should look like this:

```swift
var attributesDict = [NSNumber: Any]()
attributesDict[NSNumber(value: 2003265652)] = weight
```

Attribute ID can be obtained as follows:

```swift
let variationAxes = (CTFontCopyVariationAxes(ctFont)! as Array)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. Btw, this number is just the four ascii characters of "wght" (the registered OpenType axis) interpreted as UInt32 (0x77676874)